# How can I get co-ordinates of a dropped pin in a webView that has a link of google maps embedded on android?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, android-webview, coordinates

How can I get co-ordinates of a dropped pin in a webView that has a link of google maps embedded on android? I need to get the co-ordinates to store it in a mySQL database

This is my [webview](http://tinypic.com/r/otnghh/8)
. I want to get the values of the co-ordinates of [this](http://tinypic.com/r/2ynp7ig/8) dropped pin

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below solution it might help you

http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:38.9419+-78.3020

- z is the zoom level (1-20)
- t is the map type ("m" map, "k" satellite, "h" hybrid, "p" terrain,
  "e" GoogleEarth)
- q is the search query, if it is prefixed by loc: then google assumes
  it is a lat lon separated by a +

Hope it will work for you.

Let me know if you need more help from my side on same.

Comment: thanks for the link. But what I want is, when I search for a location and it drops the pin, how can I get the two values of the lat and long, so that I can send it to the database?

Comment: You can make webservice and using GET webservice you can store in Mysql database on the server

Comment: what exactly do you mean by webservice? @Vatsal Shah

Comment: Like you want to store latitude and longitude in your database am I right ?

Comment: yes. I am wondering what code to add in the android .java files, to get the values of the latitude and longitude of the pin

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the URL: `String str = webView.getURL()`.

Next, convert it to an Uri: `Uri uri = Uri.parse(str)`.

Lastly, call `getQueryParameter(key)` to get the latitude and longitude values: `uri.getQueryParameter(q)`.

Comment: Sorry to ask, what is "q" in getQueryParameter? In the documentation it says String key. But what is key? I'm new to android. Sorry

Comment: getQueryParameter returns the value of a String key, which is what the documentation means. "q" is the key and refers to the parameter in the URL under that name. Take Vatsal's example, for example. It has a portion that goes "q=loc: ..." The value of q is the latitude and longitude. I hope it won't confuse you but you may want to read about the key-value pair in programming. "q" is your String key, and it is linked to a value, which happens to be latitude and longitude.

Comment: oh, right. I get it now. I'll try and see. Thanks loads